# Ubuntu doesn't send out Router advertisement to its link partner

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have 2 systems connected via Arista switch.
System1 ---Arista switch ----System2

I see System1 receives Router solicitation from System2
IP6  > ip6-allrouters: ICMP6, router solicitation

But System1 doesn't respond with router Advertisement.

I am basically trying to do ipv6 ping between the system1 and 2 but it fails so debugging where and why its failing.

Any pointers will help. Thank you!

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu? Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Its a network related issue, so I tagged it with network and ipv6. Where can this question be posted?